# How to plot floating values on a graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot FRED's economic data using matplotlib/seaborn, But the values themselves are in floating points and matplotlib instead of using range, quite literally just uses all the values as distinct y-axis points, something like [image: this]. I need to plot this in a way where the changes are apparent. I tried to specify y axis range by using yticks, but it still does not work. Here's my code

```
mort30=pd.read_csv('Dataset/MORTGAGE30US.csv')
mort30['DATE']= pd.DateTimeIndex(mort30['DATE']).years # to get only year values on the x-axis
sns.lineplot(data=mort30, x='DATE', y='MORTGAGE30US')
plt.yticks(np.arange(1,11,step=1))
```

Any other ideas that could work? [Here](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/MORTGAGE30US) is the dataset link for the graph (P.S. go to edit graph and change frequency to Annual for simplicity)

Comment: If the y-axis is numeric, the time series change will be represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your y-data are objects, not numerical values. Take a look to the CSV, the last line contains no number.

```py
mort30['MORTGAGE30US']

47     4.5446153846153846
48     3.9357692307692308
49     3.1116981132075472
50                      .
Name: MORTGAGE30US, dtype: object
```

Next time add a running example, please. Your shown code is not working, it should be:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

mort30=pd.read_csv('MORTGAGE30US.csv')
mort30['DATE']= pd.DatetimeIndex(mort30['DATE']).year # to get only year values on the x-axis
sns.lineplot(data=mort30, x='DATE', y='MORTGAGE30US')
plt.yticks(np.arange(1,11,step=1))
```

Comment: Thank you, I just assumed they would be float values, I'll keep it in mind in future